# Custom Pagelayouts vs Visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, page-layout

To save/edit values in a custom object which should be used -custom Pagelayouts or visualforce page and why? what are the pros and cons of both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pagelayouts - Default functionality, modifable via clicks not code

Visualforce - Highly customizable - Inclusion of javascript and functionality not available in standard page layouts. - Only modifiable by someone who know how to write in Visualforce and potentially apex

If you do not need branding or custom control over processes entering data the stick with the standard page layouts.

Comment: "Configuration over code"; it's our mantra.